# Convert tabbed text to html unordered list?

Tags: python, html

I'm a beginner programmer so this question might sound trivial: I have some text files containg tab-delimited text like:

```
A
    B
    C
        D
        E
```

Now I want to generate unordered .html lists out of this, with the structure:

```
<ul>
<li>A
<ul><li>B</li>
<li>C
<ul><li>D</li>
<li>E</li></ul></li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

My idea was to write a Python script, but if there is an easier (automatic) way, that is fine too. For identifying the indentation level and item name I would try to use this code:

```
import sys
indent = 0
last = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    count = 0
    while line.startswith("\t"):
       count += 1
       line = line[1:]
    if count > indent:
       indent += 1
       last.append(last[-1])
    elif count < indent:
       indent -= 1
       last = last[:-1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tokenize` module](http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize) understands your input format: lines contain a valid Python identifiers, the indentation level of the statements is significant. [`ElementTree` module](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) allows you to manipulate tree structures in memory so it might be more flexable to separate a tree creation from a rendering it as html:

```
from tokenize import NAME, INDENT, DEDENT, ENDMARKER, NEWLINE, generate_tokens
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

def parse(file, TreeBuilder=etree.TreeBuilder):
    tb = TreeBuilder()
    tb.start('ul', {})
    for type_, text, start, end, line in generate_tokens(file.readline):
        if type_ == NAME: # convert name to <li> item
            tb.start('li', {})
            tb.data(text)
            tb.end('li')
        elif type_ == NEWLINE:
            continue
        elif type_ == INDENT: # start <ul>
            tb.start('ul', {})
        elif type_ == DEDENT: # end </ul>
            tb.end('ul')
        elif type_ == ENDMARKER: # done
            tb.end('ul') # end parent list
            break
        else: # unexpected token
            assert 0, (type_, text, start, end, line)
    return tb.close() # return root element
```

Any class that provides `.start()`, `.end()`, `.data()`, `.close()` methods can be used as a `TreeBuilder` e.g., you could just write html on the fly instead of building a tree.

To parse stdin and write html to stdout you could use [`ElementTree.write()`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write):

```
import sys

etree.ElementTree(parse(sys.stdin)).write(sys.stdout, method='html')
```

Output:

```
<ul><li>A</li><ul><li>B</li><li>C</li><ul><li>D</li><li>E</li></ul></ul></ul>
```

You can use any file, not just `sys.stdin/sys.stdout`.

Note: To write to stdout on Python 3 use `sys.stdout.buffer` or `encoding="unicode"` due to  bytes/Unicode distinction.

Answer (score 5):

Try this (works on your test case):

```
import itertools
def listify(filepath):
    depth = 0
    print "<ul>"*(depth+1)
    for line in open(filepath):
        line = line.rstrip()
        newDepth = sum(1 for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda c: c=='\t', line))
        if newDepth > depth:
            print "<ul>"*(newDepth-depth)
        elif depth > newDepth:
            print "</ul>"*(depth-newDepth)
        print "<li>%s</li>" %(line.strip())
        depth = newDepth
    print "</ul>"*(depth+1)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the algorithm goes like this:

- keep track of the current indentation level (by counting the number of tabs per line)
- if the indentation level increase: emit `<ul> <li>current item</li>`
- if the indentation level decreases: emit `<li>current item</li></ul>`
- if the indentation level remains the same: emit `<li>current item</li>`

Putting this into code is left to the OP as exercise

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm is simple. You take the depth level of a line that is indicated with a tab \t and shift the next bullet to the right \t+\t or to the left \t\t-\t or leave it at the same level \t.

Make sure your "in.txt" contains tabs or replace indent with tabs if you copy it from here. If indent is made of blank spaces nothing works. And the separator is a blank line at the end. You can change it in the code, if you want.

J.F. Sebastian's solution is fine but doesn't process unicode.

Create a text file "in.txt" in UTF-8 encoding:

```
qqq
    www
    www
        яяя
        яяя
    ыыы
    ыыы
qqq
qqq
```

and run the script "ul.py". The script will create the "out.html" and open it in Firefox.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# The script exports a tabbed list from string into a HTML unordered list.

import io, subprocess, sys

f=io.open('in.txt', 'r',  encoding='utf8')
s=f.read()
f.close()

#---------------------------------------------

def ul(s):

    L=s.split('\n\n')

    s='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">\n\
<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"><title>List Out</title></head><body>'

    for p in L:
        e=''
        if p.find('\t') != -1:

            l=p.split('\n')
            depth=0
            e='<ul>'
            i=0

            for line in l:
                if len(line) >0:
                    a=line.split('\t')
                    d=len(a)-1

                    if depth==d:
                        e=e+'<li>'+line+'</li>'


                    elif depth < d:
                        i=i+1
                        e=e+'<ul><li>'+line+'</li>'
                        depth=d


                    elif depth > d:
                        e=e+'</ul>'*(depth-d)+'<li>'+line+'</li>'
                        depth=d
                        i=depth


            e=e+'</ul>'*i+'</ul>'
            p=e.replace('\t','')

            l=e.split('<ul>')
            n1= len(l)-1

            l=e.split('</ul>')
            n2= len(l)-1

            if n1 != n2:
                msg='<div style="color: red;">Wrong bullets position.<br>&lt;ul&gt;: '+str(n1)+'<br>&lt;&frasl;ul&gt;: '+str(n2)+'<br> Correct your source.</div>'
                p=p+msg

        s=s+p+'\n\n'

    return s

#-------------------------------------      

def detach(cmd):
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    sys.exit()

s=ul(s)

f=io.open('out.html', 'w',  encoding='utf8')
s=f.write(s)
f.close()

cmd='firefox out.html'
detach(cmd)
```

HTML will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"><title>List Out</title></head><body><ul><li>qqq</li><ul><li>www</li><li>www</li><ul><li>яяя</li><li>яяя</li></ul><li>ыыы</li><li>ыыы</li></ul><li>qqq</li><li>qqq</li></ul>
```