# Python - lxml - how to 'move' around the tree when building the tree

Tags: python, lxml

Basic question - how do you 'move' around in a tree when you are building a tree.

I can populate the first level:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

def main():
    root = ET.Element('baseURL')
    root.attrib["URL"]='www.com'
    root.attrib["title"]='Level Title'
    myList = [["www.1.com","site 1 Title"],["www.2.com","site 2 Title"],["www.3.com","site 3 Title"]]   
    for i in xrange(len(myList)):
        ET.SubElement(root, "link_"+str(i), URL=myList[i][0], title=myList[i][1])
```

This gives me something like:

```
baseURL:
        link_0
        link_1
        link_2
```

from there, I want to add a subtree from each of the new nodes so it looks something like:

```
baseURL:
        link_0:
               link_A
               link_B
               link_C
        link_1
        link_2
```

I can't see how to 'point' the subElement call to the next node down - I tried:

```
myList2 = [["www.A.com","site A Title"],["www.B.com","site B Title"],["www.C.com","site C Title"]]
for i in xrange(len(myList2)):
        ET.SubElement('link_0', "link_"+str(i), URL=myList2[i][0], title=myList2[i][1])
```

But that throws the error:

`TypeError: Argument '_parent' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got str)`

as I am giving the subElement call a string, not an element reference. I also tried it as a variable, (i.e. `link_0' rather than`"link_0"`) and that gives a global missing variable, so my reference is obviously incorrect.

How do I 'point' my lxml builder to a child as a parent, and write a new child?

Comment: unrelated: you can [build xml tree from indented text using TreeBuilder and tokenizer module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12166627/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ET.SubElement(parent_node,type)` creates a new XML element node as a child of `parent_node`. It also returns this new node.

So you could do this:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

def main():
  root = ET.Element('baseURL')
  myList = [1,2,3]
  children = []
  for x in myList:
    children.append( ET.SubElement(root, "link_"+str(x)) )

  for y in myList:
     ET.SubElement( children[0], "child_"+str(y) )
```

But keeping track of the children is probably excessive since lxml already provides you with many ways to get to them.

Here's a way using lxmls built in children lists:

```
 node = root[0]
 for y in myList:
   ET.SubElement( node, "child_"+str(y) )
```

Here's a way using XPath (possibly better if your XML is getting ugly)

```
 node = root.xpath("/baseURL/link_0")[0]
 for y in myList:
   ET.SubElement( node, "child_"+str(y) )
```

Comment: Thank you. I was just (about) reaching the answer, but yours is (obviously) much more complete, and extremely useful. I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I should be using the python array referencing, `root[n]` not trying to get to it via `list_0`