# Parsing an ad-hoc tree

Tags: python, xml, json, algorithm, tree

I have a flat file that appears as follows:

```
Soccer

+Team:US
++Shirt:Red & White Stripes
++Shorts:Blue
++Players:17
+++Active:11
++++Forward:2
++++Midfield:4
++++Defense:4
++++Goalkeeper:1
+++Substitute:6
++++Forward:1
++++Midfied:2
++++Defense:3
++++Goalkeeper:

+Team:Mexico
++Shirt:Green
++Shorts:White
++Players:17
+++Active:11
++++Forward:3
++++Midfield:3
++++Defense:4
++++Goalkeeper:1
+++Substitute:6
++++Forward:2
++++Midfield:1
++++Defense:2
++++Goalkeeper:1
```

What is the most efficient way to parse this into a data structure in Python? Or otherwise, how would I convert this into XML, JSON or a plain Python object?

The resulting data structure should be able to support some kind of querying, for example in psuedocode such as:

```
Soccer[Team='US'][Shirt]
```

should be able to return "Red & White Stripes"

Similarly something of the order of,

```
Soccer[Team='US'][Players][Substitute][Goalkeeper]
```

should return None

Is there a module that'll be of use here?

Comment: You can create this data structure yourself without any library. You see that '+' in the front will help you to know whether you are in the same team or moved to next one. Just create a dictionary and read the file line by line, appropriately adding into the dict.

Comment: parsing is strait forward as Vivek Rai pointed out if you are too lazy to code the DB and query engine you can still use MySQL for that ... just parse your file and send it to MySQL ... did not use it under Python but C++ and PHP API works well for me ...

Comment: @Spektre - I am not sure I follow you. What DB? What query engine? What I am looking for is a module for tree parsing? I, like others can see very well how the data is structured. I would imagine that whoever wrote lxml or a similar module may have had to go through the same problem and want to find if there is a generic solution.

Comment: related: [Convert tabbed text to html unordered list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12163967/4279)

Answer (score 2):

For such thing you can use [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2), a [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) interface to [Marpa, a general BNF parser](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html) — [parser](https://gist.github.com/rns/916bbdc8d87bf9dc3f4e#file-parser-pl), [parse tree](https://gist.github.com/rns/916bbdc8d87bf9dc3f4e#file-parse-tree). Some more explanations are in my answer to related question [Processing repeatedly structured text file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184812/processing-repeatedly-structured-text-file-with-python?lq=1)

Example of `ast_traverse()`: [Parse values from a block of text based on specific keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179905/parse-values-from-a-block-of-text-based-on-specific-keys/26182278#26182278)